# Problema ao redirecionar DNS Próprio para um ip fora do meu servidor.

Tags: dns, redes

Tenho um domínio: www.servidortt.com.br e tenho outros sites da minha mesma empresa que usam  ns1.servidortt.com.br, ns2.servidortt.com.br para poderem ficar disponíveis.

Desenvolvi o site do domínio principal www.servidortt.com.br em Node e precisei ir para a DigitalOcean. porem como faço para que meus outros sites que precisam do DNS continue indo para o servidor antigo ?

Crio uma CNAME ?

Crio uma AA ?

Answer (score 2):

Você deve criar o registro tipo AA apontando para o ip aonde se encontra hospedado a aplicação/site

Comment: Muito obrigado. Criei um AA e depois criei um CNAME que chama esse AA.